# Orchard CMS @IF statement in Layout

Tags: razor, content-management-system, orchardcms

Any idea how to change the layout in Orchard CMS if an @IF statement.

Basically on the homepage I require an additional  so I need If homepage { (then do this) } Else { do that}

```
@if (Request.Url.ToString ().Equals("http://localhost:5603/"))
{
<h1>Shows on HomePage</h1>
             }
else
{
<h1>Sows on Everything Else</h1>   
}
```

EDIT:

Its dirty but it works for me

```
@if (Request.Url.ToString().EndsWith("/"))
{
<h1>Shows on HomePage</h1>
}
else
{
<h1>Sows on Everything Else</h1>   
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some example code? Anything you've already tried?

Comment: Sorry I was at work at the time :-)

Comment: @if (Request.Url.ToString ().Equals("http://localhost:5603/"))
                 {
                 <h1>Shows on HomePage</h1>
                 }
                 else
                {

                   <h1>Sows on Everything Else</h1>   
                 
                }

Comment: But I don't want to use LocalHost for the HomePage I have tried "/" but still shows on all pages

Answer (score 1):

Learn how the layers and widgets work and you will be able to place any information where you want, based on a rule (ex : url = ~/) :
http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Managing-widgets